# How to configure registries.yaml to point to several Harbor proxy cache registry?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry, registry, containerd

I have configured a **[Harbor](https://goharbor.io)** (with SSL and FQDN: harbor.example.com) as a *proxy cache* for several docker registries (docker.io, quay.io and k8s.gcr.io). I can pull any images without any problem from any PC/VM which can access the Harbor netowrk, i.e.:

```
# From hub.docker.com
docker pull harbor.example.com/dockerhub/library/ubuntu:20.04
# From quay.com
docker pull harbor.example.com/q/metallb/speaker:v0.12.1
# From k8s.gcr.com
docker pull harbor.example.com/g/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.1.2@sha256:28b11ce69e57843de44e3db6413e98d09de0f6688e33d4bd384002a44f78405c
```

I want to use this Harbor to, from a local **k3s** cluster (which was an airgap installation) and its only way to pull images is using the previously mentioned **Harbor** registry (because it has no way to reach the internet), pull images from every docker proxy cache created with, for example, and following the lasts examples:

```
k3s crictl pull ubuntu:20.04
k3s crictl pull quay.io/metallb/controller:v0.12.1
k3s crictl pull k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.1.2@sha256:28b11ce69e57843de44e3db6413e98d09de0f6688e33d4bd384002a44f78405c
```

In order to get it done, and following the instructions from the [rke2 official docx](https://docs.rke2.io/install/containerd_registry_configuration/), I'm trying to modify the `/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml` to rewrite the link , i.e., from **docker.io** to *harbor.example.com/dockerhub*, and/or from **quay.io** to *harbor.example.com/q* and or **k8s.grc.io** to *harbor.example.com/g* but I can't find a way to achieve correctly... I guess it should be something like the folowing (but for every Harbor's cache proxy):

```
mirrors:
  quay.io:
    endpoint:
      - "https://harbor.virtalus.com"
    rewrite:
      "\/(.*)": "q/$1"
```

**So the question is: how to properly configure containerd's `registries.yaml` to point it to several **Harbor**'s proxy cache?**

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working with Harbor Version v2.10.0-6abb4eab using `mirror` and a tweaked URL instead of trying to rewrite image names on the fly:

1. Follow the docs at https://goharbor.io/docs/2.1.0/administration/configure-proxy-cache/ to create a project called `proxy_cache`, setup security or make the mirror public
2. If using your own CA copy the `pem` file somewhere on each k3s node
3. `registries.yaml` should look something like this. I have robot user and my own CA.

```yaml
mirrors:
  docker.io:
    endpoint:
      - "https://harbor.example.com/v2/proxy_cache"
configs:
  "harbor.example.com":
    auth:
      username: "robot$k3s" # this is the registry username
      password: "thisisaverysecurepasswordtoaccesspublicfiles" # this is the registry password
    tls:
      # cert_file: # path to the cert file used in the registry (mTLS)
      # key_file:  # path to the key file used in the registry (mTLS)
      ca_file: "/etc/rancher/k3s/ca.pem"  # path to the ca file used in the registry (if using TLS)
```

4. Restart k3s
5. Reference images as normal, eg

```yaml
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/kong/httpbin:0.1.0
```

or

```yaml
      containers:
      - image: kong/httpbin:0.1.0
```

I automated the copying the CA and the registry.yaml to my k3s servers with some ansibles like this:

```yaml
- name: registries
  hosts: server
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: registries.yaml
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: registries.yaml 
      dest: /etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: '0600'

  - name: ca.pem
    ansible.builtin.copy:
      src: ~/ca/ca.pem
      dest: /etc/rancher/k3s/ca.pem
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: '0600'

  - name: k3s
    ansible.builtin.systemd_service:
      state: restarted
      name: k3s
```